# how to pass argument to button onclick inside template literal when looping

Tags: javascript, loops, web, scope

```
function show(x){
  console.log(x)
}

users.forEach(item => {
    let content = document.createElement("div")
    content.classList.add("content")
    content.innerHTML = `                      
                 <input type="button" id='add_deposit' value="add" onclick="show(${item})"   /
`;
  list.append(content)
```

it outputs identifier not found. how do i pass corrosponding item inside button onclick function

Comment: What is in `users`?

Comment: For example, if you had strings, then `show(${item})` would evaluate to `show(xyz)`, not `show("xyz")`.

Comment: User contains object of user with key of amount, transaction. When we click button I want to increase amount key value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener` so that the click handler can see the `item` in its closure. Inline handlers can only reference global variables, which doesn't work well inside a loop (or, at all, often) - best to avoid them whenever possible.

You also shouldn't use the `add_deposit` ID - there should only be at most one element with a particular ID in a document.

```
users.forEach(item => {
    const content = document.createElement("div")
    content.classList.add("content")
    content.innerHTML = `                      
                 <input type="button" value="add" />
    `;
    content.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
        show(item);
    });
    list.append(content)
});
```